# how to check if focus switches from one text view to another

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitextview

I've got 2 UITextFields. I can detect when the user in inside either of them with:

```
textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
```

Which works great. But i want the textfields to animate out when the user is not inside either of them. Currently I'm calling: `(void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField`

However, this is called even if i switch from on textfield to the other. Is there a better way to call do this?

Comment: Never call the delegate methods yourself.

Comment: thats not really helpful, why should I not call them?

Comment: The delegate methods will get called by the text view and the underlying framework when it is appropriate. If you ever find yourself explicitly calling a delegate method then you are doing something wrong. This, of course, doesn't apply to the implementation of a class that provides its own protocol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I would do is add a `BOOL` flag to detect if you should animate out your text fields or not. It would work something like this:

```
-(void)hideTextFields {
    if (self.shouldHideTextFields) {
        self.textField1.hidden = YES; // Or whatever you want to do with 
        self.textField2.hidden = YES; // your text fields
    }
}
```

- Declare a method that checks the BOOL flag and decides whether to hide or not the text fields
- Whenever either of the `textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField` methods are called set the BOOL flag (you can call it 'shouldHideTextFields') to `NO`.
- Whenever either of the `textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField` methods are called set the BOOL flag to 'YES'. Also, call `[self performSelector:@selector(hideTextFields) withObject:nil afterDelay:1];` to give the user a little time to select the other text field. If he/she does, the flag will be set to `NO` thanks to the above step.

Hope this helps!

Comment: @James Dunay, were you able to try this solution? Do you have any more questions?

Answer (score 0):

On `didend` check if either of your textviews is currently the first responder with `[textfield isFirstResponder]` or `[textfield isEditing]`.  There may be a slight delay when one ends and the other takes control.  If that's the case then you could do this check after a slight delay using `performSelector:afterDelay`.

Answer (score 0):

On textFieldDidEndEditing delegate method, do not just perform your disappearing animations, but do that in dispatch_async, checking if there is no textField editing right now.
In case if user just ended editing of one text field, there will be no editing textfield. But if user had switched to another textfield, it will already start editing and it can be easily checked by isFirstResponder method.